# ¿Cómo centro mi banner con css?

Tags: html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero centrar esa imagen horizontalmente pero también verticalmente como mas o menos se ve aqui https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/home.html sino que quitando la foto de arriba ya el banner se va todo para arriba otra cosa que quiero hacer es que la imagen sea responsive desing, es decir que se adapte tanto a celulales y tabletas,
este es mi codigo tambien incluyo el codigo de el menu

```html
<aside class="arriba">
    <h3></h3>
    <p>
      <img class="banner" src="imagenes/alexandraw.jpg">
    </p>
  </aside>

  <nav>
  <ul><li>
<div class="contenedor">
     <a href="#" class="open">INICIO</a>
  </div>
</li>
    <li><div class="contenedor">
      <a href="#openmodal1" class="open"> ACERCA DE </a>
      <section id="openmodal1" class="modalDialog">
        <section class="modal">
          <a href="#close" class="close"> X </a>
          <h2 class="diferencia"> acerca de</h2>
          <p class="diferente">Este sitio abarca tutoriales para dar soluciones destinadas a resolver dudas acerca de todo tipo de ideas útiles para el internauta</p>
        </section>
      </section>
    </div></li>
    <li><div class="contenedor">
      <a href="#openmodal2" class="open">POLITICA DE PRIVACIDAD</a>
      <section id="openmodal2" class="modalDialog">
        <section class="modal">
          <a href="#close" class="close"> X </a>
          <h2 class="diferencia"> politica de privacidad</h2>
          <p class="diferente">Esta permitido compartir todo el contenido de este sitio, más no está permitido copiar cual fiel copia, para usarlo en el desarrollo de otro sitio web, todo o parte del contenido de mi sitio web. En cualquier caso que se inserte cualquier parte del contenido en otro sitio web se deberá hacer referencia de que se está compartiendo el contenido y de forma notoria que dicho contenido es de mi autoria: Susana Alexadra Loor García y de que se extrajo de: <a href="https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com">https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/</a> Por lo tanto se establece que se respetará este sitio web como propiedad de la autora, y nadie se podrá adujudicar a su autoria todo del contenido de dicho sitio</p>
        </section>
      </section>
    </div></li>
    <li><div class="contenedor">
      <a href="#openmodal3" class="open"> CONTACTO</a>
      <section id="openmodal3" class="modalDialog">
        <section class="modal">
          <a href="#close" class="close"> X </a>
          <h2 class="diferencia"> CONTACTO</h2>
          <p class="diferente">Comunicate con nosotros a este correo susanaloorgarcia@gmail.com</p>
        </section>
      </section>
    </div> </li>
    <li>
       <div class="contenedor">
        <a target="_blank" class="open" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsYcSASeuWbHFBZJXy6SJEA?sub_confirmation=1">YOUTUBE</a>
       </div>
 </li>
  </ul>
      </nav>
```

compañero que me ayudastes muchas gracias pero no ha quedado bien[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] mi banner original mide 1349 x 89 px

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando subo los cambios con git push heroku master igual aparece asi, subi un ultimo cambio recientemente con los codigos que me distes y no sale igual al de la imagen que estoy adjutando aqui, igual la imagen tiene un defecto que se le ve lo negro al lado derecho. Este es mi codigo el cual esta icluido el ultimo codigo que me distes

```css
* *, *::before, *::after{ box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
    body {
 background: #000000;
 color: #000000;
} 
header, footer {
 background: #000000;
 width: 90%;
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 30%
 margin:20% auto;

}

h2{
 text-align: center;
}
 p {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
  }
 li { /*font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;*/
  font-style: oblique; }


header nav {
 background: #000000;
 overflow: hidden;
}
header nav ul {
 list-style: none;
}
header nav ul li {
 float:right;
}
 header nav ul li a {
  padding: 3% 6%;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;


 }
  header nav ul li a:hover {
   background: #55d737;
  }
 
.main {
  background: #000000;
  display: flex;
  padding: : 0%
  
} 


.main aside,
.main .article{
  padding: 3%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.arriba {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(0, 163, 232);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.foto {
  max-width: 1.5rem;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

.banner {
  max-width: 7.5rem;
  height: auto;
}
.main .iz{
  width: 15%;
}
.main .de {
 width: 15%
}
.iz{
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
  order: 1;
}

.de{
  background: white;
  order: 3;
}

.article{
  order: 2;
  width: 70%;
  background: white;
}

article{
  background: white;
  margin: 5% auto;
}

footer {
background: #000;
color:#fff;
clear:both
padding:10% 0%;
text-align: center;
}

.centro {
 text-align: center;
}

a.open{
 background-color: #414141;
 border-radius: 5%;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 1em;
 margin: 20px;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow: 2% 2% 0% #000;
}

section.modalDialog{
 background-color: white;
 bottom: 0;
 top:0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 position: fixed;
 display: none;
 z-index: 2;
}

section.modalDialog:target{
 display: block;
}

a.close{
 background-color: #414141;
 border-radius: 5%;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 60%;
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 22%;
 position: absolute;
 right: 1%;
 top:2%;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 width: 3%;
}

a.close{
 background-color: #000;
}

section.modal{
 background-color: #111;
 box-shadow: 0% 0% 5% #000;
 border-radius: 5%;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 6% auto;
 padding: 2%;
 position: relative;
 width: 40%;

  max-height: 80vh; /*O lo que quieras o veas que se adpate mejor*/
  /*overflow: auto; u otra opción es que solo sea en la altura el scroll*/
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: none;
}



.diferencia {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 2em;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.diferente{
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 1.2em;
}




article iframe, 
article * .mobile, article .mobile {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

/** Posible Solución a la pregunta **/

@media all and (max-width:800px) {
 .main{
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 }
 .main .iz {
 display:inline-block;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 margin:0 auto;
 }
 .main .de {
 display:inline-block;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 margin:0 auto;
 }
 .de p {
 width:90%;
 margin:0 auto;
 display:inline;
 }
 .iz p {
 width:90%;
 margin:0 auto;
 display:inline;
 }
 .article {
 width:100%;
 margin:0 auto;
 }
 article {
 margin:1% auto;
 }}

 @media (max-width: 800px){
  .mobile{ 
    width: 100%;
  }

@media (max-width: 800px){
  iframe { 
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Bienvenidos</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="imagenes/ale2.jpg">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css" />
</head>
<body>
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/es_ES/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.11';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
  <header>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "VideoObject",
  "name": "enviar mensaje masivo outlook office ",
  "description": "las personas lo reciben como que si estuviera destinado solo a ellos y no como una cadena,  cada persona verá su propia dirección de correo en el mensaje y no la del resto de contactos",
  "thumbnailUrl": [
    "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/1LhkxeHZm0A/hqdefault.jpg"
   ],
  "uploadDate": "2017-10-23T19:57:00",
  "duration": "PPT4M28S",
  "embedUrl": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/1LhkxeHZm0A",
  "interactionCount": "67"
}
</script>
<aside class="arriba">
    <h3></h3>
    <img class="foto" src="./imagenes/ale2.jpg" width="70" alt="Alexandra Loor">  
      <img class="banner" src="imagenes/alexandraw.jpg">
    
  </aside>

  <nav>
  <ul><li>
<div class="contenedor">
     <a href="#" class="open">INICIO</a>
  </div>
</li>
    <li><div class="contenedor">
      <a href="#openmodal1" class="open"> ACERCA DE </a>
      <section id="openmodal1" class="modalDialog">
        <section class="modal">
          <a href="#close" class="close"> X </a>
          <h2 class="diferencia"> acerca de</h2>
          <p class="diferente">Este sitio abarca tutoriales para dar soluciones destinadas a resolver dudas acerca de todo tipo de ideas útiles para el internauta</p>
        </section>
      </section>
    </div></li>
    <li><div class="contenedor">
      <a href="#openmodal2" class="open">POLITICA DE PRIVACIDAD</a>
      <section id="openmodal2" class="modalDialog">
        <section class="modal">
          <a href="#close" class="close"> X </a>
          <h2 class="diferencia"> politica de privacidad</h2>
          <p class="diferente">Esta permitido compartir todo el contenido de este sitio, más no está permitido copiar cual fiel copia, para usarlo en el desarrollo de otro sitio web, todo o parte del contenido de mi sitio web. En cualquier caso que se inserte cualquier parte del contenido en otro sitio web se deberá hacer referencia de que se está compartiendo el contenido y de forma notoria que dicho contenido es de mi autoria: Susana Alexadra Loor García y de que se extrajo de: <a href="https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com">https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/</a> Por lo tanto se establece que se respetará este sitio web como propiedad de la autora, y nadie se podrá adujudicar a su autoria todo del contenido de dicho sitio</p>
        </section>
      </section>
    </div></li>
    <li><div class="contenedor">
      <a href="#openmodal3" class="open"> CONTACTO</a>
      <section id="openmodal3" class="modalDialog">
        <section class="modal">
          <a href="#close" class="close"> X </a>
          <h2 class="diferencia"> CONTACTO</h2>
          <p class="diferente">Comunicate con nosotros a este correo susanaloorgarcia@gmail.com</p>
        </section>
      </section>
    </div> </li>
    <li>
       <div class="contenedor">
        <a target="_blank" class="open" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsYcSASeuWbHFBZJXy6SJEA?sub_confirmation=1">YOUTUBE</a>
       </div>
 </li>
  </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <section class="main">
    <aside class="de">
    <h3></h3>
    <p><a href="paginas principales/acceso incognito.html">acceso a incognito desde el icono principal</a></p><br>
<p><a href="paginas principales/captura de pantalla.html"> capturar pantalla sin paint</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/clavewindows.html">conocer la clave de windows instalada en tu equipo</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/configmicrofono.html">configurar el microfono para que se escuche bien en audio/video</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/convertir ventana a pestaña.html">convertir ventana a pestaña y viceversa</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/cookies chrome.html">desactivar, activar cookies en chrome</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/cortar video.html">cortar video de youtube</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/direccion ip.html">conocer dns, direccion ip, gategay o puerta de enlace predeterminada y mascara de subred</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/enviar mensaje masivo.html">enviar mensaje masivo outlook office</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/excepciones avira.html">añadir excepciones a avira</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/google ncr.html">hacer busquedas globales y en cualquier idioma</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/grabadora.html">localizar los archivos de la grabadora de sonido</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/guardar sesión chrome.html">guardar sesion en chrome rapidamente</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/k de youtube.html">averigua que significa la k en youtube</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/ocultar video.html">ocultar informacion y partes de video</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/rejected git push heroku master.html">solucionar el error de rejected git push heroku master</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/traducir texto.html">traducir texto rapidamente</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/vista windows.html">gesto del mouse pack para cambio inesperado de aplicaciones en windows</a> </p><br>
  </aside>
  <aside class="iz">
    <h3></h3>
    <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Compartir</a></div>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/share?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" class="twitter-share-button" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a><script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<!-- Place this tag where you want the share button to render. -->
<div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-href="https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/"></div>
  </aside>
  <section class="article">
    <article>
      <h2>Tutoriales</h2><br>

        <p class="centro"><a href="paginas principales/rejected git push heroku master.html"><img src="imagenes/1.jpg" width="150" alt="solucion a rejeted git push heroku master" title="solucion a rejeted git push heroku master"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/enviar mensaje masivo.html"><img src="imagenes/2.jpg" width="150" alt="enviar mensaje masivo outlook office" title="enviar mensaje masivo outlook office"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/traducir texto.html"><img src="imagenes/3.jpg" width="150" alt="traducir texto rápidamente" title="traducir texto rápidamente"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/google ncr.html"><img src="imagenes/4.jpg" width="150" alt="hacer busquedas globales" title="hacer busquedas globales y en cualquier idioma google ncr"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/k de youtube.html"><img src="imagenes/6.jpg" width="150" alt="k de youtube" title="k de youtube"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/grabadora.html"><img src="imagenes/7.jpg" width="150" alt="localización de archivos de la grabadora de sonido" title="localización de archivos de la grabadora de sonido"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/clavewindows.html"><img src="imagenes/8.jpg" width="150" alt="Conocer la contraseña instalada de tu windows" title="conocer la contraseña instalada de tu windows"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/excepciones avira.html"><img src="imagenes/9.jpg" width="150" alt="añadir excepciones de avira" title="añadir excepciones de avira"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/acceso incognito.html"><img src="imagenes/10.jpg" width="150" alt="acceso directo a incognito desde el icono" title="acceso directo a incognito desde el icono google chrome"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/direccion ip.html"><img src="imagenes/11.jpg" width="150" alt="direccion ip dns etcetera" title="obtener dirección ip, gateway, dns, mascara de subred"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/vista windows.html"><img src="imagenes/12.jpg" width="150" alt="cambio de accdidenta de aplicaciones de windows 8" title="cambio de accdidenta de aplicaciones de windows 8"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/captura de pantalla.html"><img src="imagenes/13.jpg" width="150" alt="atajo para capturar pantalla sin paint" title="atajo para capturar pantalla sin paint"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/cookies chrome.html"><img src="imagenes/14.jpg" width="150" alt="desactivar cookies en chrome" title="desactivar cookies en chrome"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/configmicrofono.html"><img src="imagenes/15.jpg" width="150" alt="configurar microfono" title="configurar microfono"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/ocultar video.html"><img src="imagenes/16.jpg" width="150" alt="ocultar información de video" title="Tapar información de video"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/cortar video.html"><img src="imagenes/17.jpg" width="150" alt="cortar video de youtube" title="cortar video de youtube"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/guardar sesión chrome.html"><img src="imagenes/18.jpg" width="150" alt="guardar sesión e chrome rápidamente" title="guarda sesión en chrome rápidamente"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/convertir ventana a pestaña.html"><img src="imagenes/5.jpg" width="150" alt="convertir ventana a pestaña y vicecersa" title="convertir ventana a pestaña y vicecersa"></a></p>
    </article>
  </section>
  
  </section>
  <footer><p>Portoviejo-Manabí-Ecuador</p></footer>
       <!-- Place this tag in your head or just before your close body tag. -->
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

ya tengo mucho codigo css no se si por eso sea la razón de que lo cambios no los acepta al hacer git push heroku master, porfavor revisa mi codigoo e indocame en que parte debo colocar los codigos que me das esta es mi pagina https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/paginas%20principales/vista%20windows.html

Comment: Quieres centrar tu banner horizontal y verticalmente, y tu imagen horizontalmente?

Comment: la imagen que esta arriba del banner pienso que seria bueno quitarla

Comment: la imagen de mi foto que esta arriba de la tira de banner pienso borrarla, lo que quiero que quede centrado es el banner

Comment: porfavor que no quede con ese espacio negro a la derecha

Comment: @AlexandraLoor tu pregunta parece vandalizada ya que no se puede ver la imágen tienes algún inconveninete en que se revierda la última edición?

Comment: si puedes revertirlo hazlo

Comment: esque yo no se como

Comment: @AlexandraLoor Como en otras preguntas que has hecho, debo recomendarte que leas [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve]. El modo en que está redactada la pregunta hace que sea difícil de seguir, además, luego pareces vandalizar tu propia publicación. Tienes suficiente reputación para entrar en el [chat], si tienes dudas sobre el sitio puedes plantearlas ahí o en [meta]. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edicion**

Para tu caso en específico puedes utilizar [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Usando_las_cajas_flexibles_CSS), no necesitas que tu imagen del banner ocupe tanto espacio, puedes hacerla mas pequeña y tener tu foto y el banner en la misma linea, y al `div` (en este caso tu `aside`) asigarle el color de tu banner.

Puedes asginarle los anchos que desees a tus imágenes para lograr que quede como tu gustes

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.arriba {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(0, 163, 232);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.foto {
  max-width: 1.5rem;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

.banner {
  max-width: 7.5rem;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<aside class="arriba">
  <h3></h3>
  <p>
    <img class="foto" src="https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/imagenes/ale2.jpg" alt="Foto">
    <img class="banner" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWuPe.png" alt="Banner">
  </p>
</aside>
```

---

Para que tu imagen se adapte al ancho de la pantalla puedes asignarle el `width: 100%` o `max-width: 100%`, lo que hace el primero es decirle que la imagen sea de todo el ancho de su contenedor, que no serviría mucho si la imagen es mas pequeña que este ya que puede perder su definición, el segundo nos dice que su ancho máximo puede ser del tamaño de su contenedor, lo que la hará responsiva y no perderá su definición.

Para centrar una imagen podemos asignarle `display: block` y `margin: 0 auto`, esto la centrará en su contenedor.

En el siguiente ejemplo le asigno la clase `responsive-image` a la imagen y agrego las propiedades que mencioné

```css
.responsive-image {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img class="responsive-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Cotopaxi_volcano_2008-06-27T1322.jpg/320px-Cotopaxi_volcano_2008-06-27T1322.jpg" alt="Cotopaxi">
```

---

Para centrar tu banner podemos usar la magia del [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Usando_las_cajas_flexibles_CSS), declarando un contenedor y asignandole un alto, y con `align-items: center;` `justify-content: center;`, de esta forma

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #7cec7d;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #7ec1f2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    Estoy centrado
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tengo estas propiedades * *, *::before, *::after{ box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
    body {
 background: #000000;
 color: #000000;
}   igual le pongo lo del body?

Comment: Puedes omitir lo del body, lo puse para que quede bien en el ejemplo

Comment: el primer codigo es para la imagen que tengo arriba del banner?

Comment: no funcionó amigo

Comment: Edita tu pregunta agregando el css y html de tu banner para poder reproducir el problema y ayudarte mejor :)

Comment: ya salió solo era de cambiar el header a un 100% como me dijistes